# Filter a string variable from a file and change it

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a basic program but I'm having trouble selecting the string variables. All the variables begin with _ and then a relevant string of words follow.

Comment: Cant you store each line as a string array, then do a `text[].split(delimiter)`, and it will parse/split and store each element between the delimiter in a separate array you can work on?

Comment: how are your files structured? does each line look like this: `_variableName some relevant text` ? and than the next line something similar. Could you give an example of the input and the expected output? I think this can be solved quite simple using the `String.Split` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need to read the whole file and save it again inside the loop that goes through each line, you can instead do all your replacements then save once.

For replacement, you can use regular expression replacement. I'm not sure what kind of transformation you're looking to do on the text, but you can do something like the following (in this example I'm just transforming text to upper case):

```
string[] textLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\Users\Darren\Desktop\Hello.txt");
var results = new List<string>();

foreach(var line in textLines)
{
     var result = Regex.Replace(line, @"_(.*)\s", match =>
        {
            return $"~{match.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper()} ";
        });
    results.Add(result);
}
File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\Users\Darren\Desktop\newHello.txt", results.ToArray());
```

Instead of `return $"~{match.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper()} ";` you can place the code that transforms the text in the way you want. `match.Groups[1].Value` will contain the text after the `_` and before the space